# Unable to Dual Boot

Tags: dual-boot

I have a ubuntu 14.04 live disk and I already have widows 8.1 in my system. My system has 1Tb hard-disk. I partioned free space of 100GB to install ubuntu. But when I booted from live USB it not showing already existed partioned spaces instead it is showing 1TB as free space. Please help me in resolving this..

Comment: Is Windows fast start up still on? That is always on hibernation, so Linux cannot see Windows. Be sure to only use 14.04.3, earlier versions using any of the auto install options may erase entire drive. Either way have good full back up of Windows. Grub only boots working Windows so while Windows is working make a Windows repairCD or flash drive, so later you can fix it when it breaks.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using different burning software this works in a lot of cases.
If possible you are better using USB.
UNetbootin  or Linux Live USB Creator are the best.
I had the same problem with CD installation but Linux Live USB worked just fine.